# Hide counter for exsheets solution environment

Tags: formatting, counters, exsheets

I am using `counter-format=se.qu.` for my questions which gives the following output

[image]

In my case I want to hide the counters from solutions (so that I only get *Lösungsvorschlag.* there without the 3.1) but I want to avoid writing `\SetupExSheets{counter-format=}` and `\SetupExSheets{counter-format=se.qu.}` in front of and after every single solution respectively all the time. I tried to include those two commands in the `pre-hook` and `post-hook` properties but nothing changed.

How would you hide the counter from solutions?

---

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
    \SetupExSheets{
        counter-format=se.qu.,
        headings=block-subtitle,
        solution/print=true
        }
\begin{document}
    \begin{question}[name=Custom problem,subtitle=Cauchy product]
        Question with fancy math.
    \end{question}
    \begin{solution}[name=Custom solution.]
        A difficult solution.
    \end{solution}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am unsure whether this possible at all. As far as I understand the `exsheets` documentation the solution counter (there is none, I think!) is coupled to the `question` counter. But I am sure that omitting the solution number is no good idea

Comment: The solution numbers are just slightly redundant as my problem sheets contain a couple of problems and the respective solutions right after the problem itself. That's why I am looking to hide those counters in the first place.

Comment: Alright, but I've looked into `exsheets.sty` and the only counter being stepped is `question`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer the trick is to use a separate headings type for the solutions…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a seperate `headings` instance for the solutions which doesn't print the number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{block-no-nr}{default}{
  attach = {
    main[l,vc]title[l,vc](0pt,0pt) ;
    main[r,vc]points[l,vc](\marginparsep,0pt)
  }
}

\RenewQuSolPair
  {question}[headings=block-subtitle]
  {solution}[headings=block-no-nr]

\SetupExSheets{
  counter-format=se.qu.,
  solution/print=true ,
  question/name=Custom problem ,
  solution/name=Custom solution.
}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}[subtitle=Cauchy product]
  Question with fancy math.
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  A difficult solution.
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do understand the solution but I was wondering why you would pick this approch over the one alwaysask has suggested? I guess you like it more solely relying on functions from the package itself and not using some workarounds.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic yes: it's the built in mechanism. (The interface still needs some polishing but I'm working on it. `exsheets` still is in v0 state :) )

Comment: Fair enough - and pretty nice to get the solution from the package author himself :)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for sharing. I have a question, which might interest others as well. Right now, if I implement the code as you suggested, my solutions gets printed with two question marks, instead of the number of the corresponding question. Have you maybe encountered the same error? I "solved" the problem, by removing the numbering from the solutions labels, but it would be nice if it would work properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do as you want - use a different `counter-format` for questions vs solutions - by redefining the `question` and `solution` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
    \SetupExSheets{
        %counter-format=se.qu.,
        headings=block-subtitle,
        solution/print=true
        }

    \let\oldquestion\question
    \let\oldsolution\solution

    \renewenvironment{question}{%
        \SetupExSheets{counter-format=se.qu.}
        \oldquestion
    }

    \renewenvironment{solution}{%
        \SetupExSheets{counter-format=}
        \oldsolution
    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{question}[name=Custom problem,subtitle=Cauchy product]
        Question with fancy math.
    \end{question}
    \begin{solution}[name=Custom solution.]
        A difficult solution.
    \end{solution}

    \begin{question}[name=Custom problem,subtitle=Something else]
        Question with no math.
    \end{question}
    \begin{solution}[name=Custom solution.]
        A simple solution.
    \end{solution}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My more complex source file made `\makeatother` and `\makeatletter` necessary to include your changes but it works like a charm!